# To upload an updated version of the application to Google Play, what key .keystore should it be signed with?

Tags: google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

Do I need to create a new key or use the key with which the previous versions were signed?

Comment: To update an application in Play Store, you must use the existing keystore for sign apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to create new key to update app on play store
If you signed your app with new key then play store won't allow you to update your app on play store
**If your app is already on play store then you have to use existing key store file**